# Can we move 20,000 folders from one site to another using Power Automate flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate, move

We have around 20,000 folders inside the root of a document library, and we want to move them to another site inside the same tenant. on average each folder contain around 10 files. so will we face any issue if we try to move this number of folders using Power Automate ? we are going to use the "Move Folder" built-in action.

Regards

Comment: Hi, not quite sure if power automate would be a problem, but given the number of files to be moved, to minimize the risk, perhaps you could try using SPMT.       [Overview of the SharePoint Migration Tool (SPMT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/introducing-the-sharepoint-migration-tool)

Comment: @KarleyZhou SPMT does not support migrating from online SharePoint.. it only support migrating from on-premises environments. also i need this flow to run on the background one time each week.